# Adding refresh() to an existing command

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just a quick question with regards to jQuery as javascript is not my forte.

I need to add:

```
BackgroundCheck.refresh();
```

Into the first line of the code below before the 'fadein' kicks in:

```
        $('.icon-scroll').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            $('.icon-scroll').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow'); 
        });
```

I just don't know how to add this command into the existing code **$('.icon-scroll').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow', function(){**

I tried adding it on top or right below the first line but it doesn't seem to work the way I want.

Comment: Do you want it to run after the end of the fade out? (You can use a callback inside the `fadeOut()` in the same way as the `fadeIn()` to wait for it to finish)

Comment: you can incorporate `.promise().done()` functions

Comment: @DBS - ideally with fadein or before it.